# second window run first how to stop it

Tags: python, tkinter

when i run python file kill_app its run first 2nd python file(Hb_test.py) then run 1st python on tkinter.i am using vs code and python version is 3.10
see the code below

```
from tkinter import*
from Lab.Hb_Test import Hba
class kill_App:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")
        self.root.title("Billing Software")
        bg_color = "#074463"
        title = Label(self.root,text = "PATHOLAB",bd=12,relief=GROOVE,bg=bg_color,fg="white",
        font = ("ALGERIAN",40),pady=2).pack(fill=X)

if __name__=="__main__":   
    root =Tk()
    obj = kill_App(root)
    root.mainloop()
****
```

this is my second
**

```
**from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
class Hba:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("300x70+200+200")
        self.root.title("JIBAN PRABHA PATHOLAB")
        bg_color = "#074463"
        Hb = LabelFrame(self.root,text="BLOOD TEST",font=("ALGERIAN",15,"bold")
        ,fg="gold",bg=bg_color)
        Hb.place(x=0,y=0)
        self.hb_neu_lbl = Label(Hb,text="Hb%(sahils) Test",bg=bg_color,fg="white",font=("Bell MT",15,"bold")).grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.hb_neu=Entry(Hb,width=10,font="BellMT 15",bd=5,relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=1,column=2,padx=5,pady=5)
root =  Tk()
obj = Hba(root)
root.mainloop()**
```

**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: First don't create more than one instance of `Tk()` and call `.mainloop()` more than once.  Also it is better that `Hba` inherits from `Toplevel` class.

Comment: i am new on python can u help me sir/madam

Answer (score 0):

When `Hb_Test` is imported, its code will be executed, so the last three lines in the module will create a window:

## Hb_Test.py

```py
...
# below lines will create a window
root =  Tk()
obj = Hba(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Note that it is not recommended to create more than one instance of `Tk()` and execute `.mainloop()` more than once.

For window other than the *main/root* window, use `Toplevel` instead of `Tk`.  For your case, I would suggest that `Hba` inherits from `Toplevel`:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Hba(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("300x70+200+200")
        self.title("JIBAN PRABHA PATHOLAB")
        bg_color = "#074463"
        Hb = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="BLOOD TEST", font=("ALGERIAN",15,"bold"), fg="gold", bg=bg_color)
        Hb.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.hb_neu_lbl = tk.Label(Hb, text="Hb%(sahils) Test", bg=bg_color, fg="white", font=("Bell MT",15,"bold"))
        self.hb_neu_lbl.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.hb_neu = tk.Entry(Hb, width=10, font="BellMT 15", bd=5, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
        self.hb_neu.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=5,pady=5)
```

Note that I have changed `from tkinter import *` to `import tkinter as tk` because wildcard import is not recommended as well.

Also don't write code like below:

```py
self.hb_neu_lbl = Label(Hb,text="Hb%(sahils) Test",bg=bg_color,fg="white",font=("Bell MT",15,"bold")).grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
```

because `self.hb_neu_lbl` will be `None` (result of `.grid(...)`). Code like below instead:

```py
self.hb_neu_lbl = Label(Hb, text="Hb%(sahils) Test", bg=bg_color, fg="white", font=("Bell MT",15,"bold"))
self.hb_neu_lbl.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
```